# Chef server upgrade issue - encoding on non-encoding capable object

Tags: chef-infra, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my existing chef server from `12.19.31` to `13.3.1`.

I built this version using the instructions on https://github.com/chef/chef-server

Then I installed the package.

```
sudo dpkg -i chef-server-core_13.3.1+20201008233604-1_amd64.deb (Reading database ... 153055 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack chef-server-core_13.3.1+20201008233604-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking chef-server-core (13.3.1+20201008233604-1) over (12.19.31-1) ... Setting up chef-server-core (13.3.1+20201008233604-1) ... You have upgraded Chef Server!

The next step in the upgrade process is to run:

chef-server-ctl upgrade

After the upgrade command completes, your Chef services will remain in a down state. To bring them back up run:

chef-server-ctl start

Then, to remove configuration files, logs, directories, users, etc. that were used by internal services that have been removed from this version of Chef Server, please run:

chef-server-ctl cleanup

(Add the '--no-op' option to see what would be removed by this command)

For detailed upgrade instructions please see: https://docs.chef.io/upgrade_server.html
```

Then I ran the command `chef-server-ctl upgrade`

```
------------------------------------------------------------------- The service postgresql is running externally and cannot be managed vi
chef-server-ctl.  Please log into chef-dev-db-tawny.tinyspeck.com to
manage it directly.
------------------------------------------------------------------- /opt/opscode/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-3.34.1/lib/sequel/database/schema_generator.rb:19:
warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-3.34.1/lib/sequel/database/schema_generator.rb:19:
warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated [private-chef-upgrade] -
ERROR: migration-level not initialized. [private-chef-upgrade] -
ERROR: If this is an existing Chef Server install try running
`chef-server-ctl rebuild-migration-state` and then retry the upgrade
```

Finally I ran `sudo chef-server-ctl rebuild-migration-state` and I'm getting the following error,

```
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-3.34.1/lib/sequel/database/schema_generator.rb:19:
warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sequel-3.34.1/lib/sequel/database/schema_generator.rb:19:
warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated [private-chef-upgrade] -
Infering migration-level from system state bundler: failed to load
command: ./bin/partybus (./bin/partybus) ArgumentError: cannot set
encoding on non-encoding capable object  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/lib/partybus/migration_api/v1.rb:123:in
`exec'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/lib/partybus/migration_api/v1.rb:123:in
`check_sqitch'   (eval):13:in `block in load_migration'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/lib/partybus/migration_api/v1.rb:16:in
`instance_eval'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/lib/partybus/migration_api/v1.rb:16:in
`initialize'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/lib/partybus/dsl_runner.rb:42:in
`new'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/lib/partybus/dsl_runner.rb:42:in
`run_check'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/lib/partybus/dsl_runner.rb:25:in
`check'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/lib/partybus/migrations.rb:46:in
`run_check'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/bin/partybus:90:in `block in
infer_migration_state'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/bin/partybus:89:in `each'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/bin/partybus:89:in
`infer_migration_state'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/bin/partybus:168:in `block in
<top (required)>'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/bin/partybus:159:in `open'  
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/partybus/bin/partybus:159:in `<top
(required)>'
```

I'm stuck and can't figure out what's going on. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same exact issue (except for slightly different versions) and was able to solve the issue with the following steps:

1. Deploy a new chef infra server using the version you're migrating **from** (i.e. v12.19.31)
2. Copy `/var/opt/opscode/upgrades/migration-level` from the new server (created in step 1) to the original server you're trying to upgrade.
3. Re-run `chef-server-ctl upgrade` on the server you're trying to upgrade.